# How can Go's race detector be aware of lock?

Tags: go, concurrency, synchronization, race-condition, goroutine

Adding lock to a program with race condition can solve the race condition and make the race detector quiet. How can Go's race detector be aware of lock?

Someone points out that "the race detector can only detect race conditions *if* and *when* they actually occur".

Consider the following program:

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var a int
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    workers := 2
    wg.Add(workers)
    for i := 1; i <= workers; i++ {
        go func(sleep int) {
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(sleep) * time.Second)
            a = 1
            wg.Done()
        }(i * 5)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

One goroutine sleeps for 5 seconds, another sleeps for 10 seconds, they don't write `a` at the same time in most cases, but the race detector prints the race condition warning every time. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The race detector does not analyze the source code, it doesn't know that you added locks in the source code.

The race detector works at runtime:

> When the `-race` command-line flag is set, the compiler instruments all memory accesses with code that records when and how the memory was accessed, while the runtime library watches for unsynchronized accesses to shared variables.

Because of this design, the race detector can only detect race conditions *if* and *when* they actually occur. So when you add proper locking / synchronization, the race condition will not happen (the *if* condition will not be met), and so no warning will be printed.

See this blog post for more details: [**Introducing the Go Race Detector**](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector)

And this article: [Data Race Detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html)

**Edit for your example:**

It may be that your 2 goroutines will never reach the point where they write the shared variable `a` at the same physical time (because the code runs so fast and the sleep time is relatively huge), but they run *concurrently*, in different goroutines, *without explicit synchronization* (a synchronization point may be channel communication, mutex lock/unlock etc.).

The race condition does not imply that access to a shared variable *does happen* at the same time (one of which must be a write). The race condition is also met if access to a shared variable happens *concurrently* (from multiple goroutines), without synchronization. This can be detected at runtime by the race detector (due to the instrumented memory access code).

Code generated by the compiler is allowed to use *cached* instances of the `a` variable in multiple goroutines, the runtime only has to guarantee that the cached instances are "refreshed" or disposed of if a synchronization point is reached. For details, see [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem).

Also note that [`time.Sleep()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Sleep) does not guarantee that execution will continue right after the specified duration, only that execution will be suspended for *at least* the specified duration (so the execution may continue at a *later* time):

> Sleep pauses the current goroutine for **at least** the duration d.

Comment: @小明湖畔 The race detector detects potential race conditions, not only actual race conditions. It notices that memory is read/written from different goroutines without a lock - the time between that access is not a factor in the race detection. (And your particular code gives no guarantee that there will never be a race condition - particularly in situations where the machine is overloaded, your time.Sleep() might cause all goroutines to be scheduled at the same time and create a real race)

Answer (score 0):

The data race detector does not do static analysis. It is not aware of your lock. It’s empirical, it just *notices* that when you run your code with the lock, two threads are never writing to the same value at the same time (or one writing, one reading).